# How to update child component properties from event in parent component

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a parent component that manages a variety things. When an event finishes in the parent, I want to to force the child components to refresh or trigger a method they have. Is it possible to do this? Thank you.

For instance, the component has a color property. Based on the change in state from the parent component, I want the child to change its color accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a child component like this:

### Child.razor

```
<p>Selected Color: @SelectedColor</p>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string SelectedColor { get; set; }
}
```

The code above define a public property whose value is displayed in the view part of the component. Note that the property is annotated with the Parameter attribute. Next we are going to define a parent component within which the child component is embedded. The parent component is providing ta string value for the 
SelectedColor defined above.

### Parent.razor

```
@page "/parent"

<p><input type="text" @bind="@MyColor" /></p>

<Child SelectedColor="@MyColor" />

@code
{
   private string MyColor;

}
```

In the parent component is an input Html element that is bound to a variable named MyColor. This type of binding is called two-way binding. From the variable (MyColor) to the input element and vice versa. Now when you enter a named color, and tab out of the text box, the MyColor variable contains the text you entered, and as you can see, it is assigned to the SelectedColor attribute of the child component. Thus, each time you enter a value and tab out of the text box, the parent component is re-rendering the child component with the new value entered.

This is only the beginning, and you've much to learn...start with the docs, and come here to ask questions...